# Website ul / li changes from horizontal to vertical when browser gets too small

Tags: html, resize, html-lists

I have created a website that looks correct when the browser is big enough. But as you resize the browser and make it smaller, the filter section (ul with li items), changes from being horizontal to vertical.

If you go to the website www.andrewsimonmcallister.tv. Click on the music menu item.

The section that has the subtitle, followed by the filter section looks ok when the browser is wide enough but as you shrink the browser the entire thing changes to a vertical list with dots. Is there anyway to make the sort options stack horizontally, but within their container, then make the filter options stack, but keep the filter and sort sections horizontal.

Also, the same with the description section on the music list. I would like the text to wrap underneath, but stay within the description part, not go under the title.

All help would be great.

Ok now for the code

**HTML**

**The top filter section**

Music
                Filter:
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Orchestral
                
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Electronic
                
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Other
                
                Display:
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Soundtrack
                
                
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    Advertisement

**The Description section**

```
<ul>
                                <li class="tracknumber">                                        
                                    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" style="display:inline-block;">
                                        <div class="jp-type-single">
                                            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                                                <ul class="jp-controls">
                                                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">&nbsp;</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">&nbsp;</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div name="prog1" class="jp-progress">
                                                    <div name="seek1" class="jp-seek-bar">
                                                        <div name="play1" class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="number1" class="number">1</div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="tracktitle">Beginnings</li>
                                <li class="tracktime">2:04</li>
                                <li class="trackprogress"><div id="trackprogress1" class="trackprogressbar"></div></li>
                                <li class="trackcat">Orchestral</li>
                                <li class="trackdescription">Lush sweeping strings in this opening credits cue.</li>
                            </ul>
```

** CSS **

```
.contentinformation {
padding-left: 10px;
color: #303234;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0;
}

.contentfilterlist {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

.contentfilteritem {
display:inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}

.contentfiltertitle {
padding-left: 10px; 
padding-right: 10px; 
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 18px; 
letter-spacing: 0;
}

.contentfilteroption {
padding-left: 8px;  
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.contentfiltertext {
padding-right: 6px; 
vertical-align: middle;
letter-spacing: 0;
font-size: 13px;
font-variant: small-caps;
}

.contentfilterdivide {
padding-right: 80px;
}

.contentmain {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 40px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 100px;
z-index: 11;
}

/****************************************
* Music
****************************************/
.tracktitle{
display:inline-block;
width: 250px;
}

.tracktime{
    display:inline-block;
width: 55px;
}

.trackprogress{
    display:inline-block;
width: 110px;
}

.trackprogressbar {
background: url("../images/music/progress-bg.gif") 0 0 repeat-x;
width:80px;
height:8px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0.5;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 12;
}

.trackcat {
    display:inline-block;
width: 135px;
}

.trackdescription{
    display:inline;
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!!

Thansk!

Comment: You should use `table`, not `ul`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought table was not really used anymore and had been replaced by UL?

Comment: No, `table` is by no means deprecated. If you have tabular data, you should use `table`. You probably heard the term "tableless web design", but that does "only" mean that you shouldn't use `table` for the _layout_ of your whole webpages.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use the `table` element here:

```
<table>

<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Tracknumber</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Progress</th>
  <th>Category</th>
  <th>Description</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Beginnings</td>
  <td>2:04</td>
  <td><div id="trackprogress1" class="trackprogressbar"></div></td>
  <td>Orchestral</td>
  <td>Lush sweeping strings in this opening credits cue.</td>
 </tr>

<tr>
 <td>…</td>
 <td>…</td>
 <td>…</td>
 <td>…</td>
 <td>…</td>
 <td>…</td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```